Font File Creation Error in FO Designer (FOP)
I have encountered an error while adding new fonts to a TTF file in the FO designer and attempting to generate XML. The error message states "Cannot create file: Reached EOF, file size=45312." This indicates that the file creation process is failing due to unexpectedly reaching the end of the file.
Here are a few steps I have already  already taken to troubleshoot the issue:

I have reduced the space size of the FO designer.
I have tried using other fonts.
I have attempted to clear the space.

However, the issue persists. So anyone who has faced this issue before please help me?
Please find the screenshots while clicking on create XML i am facing issue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Does this happen with one specific font file, or with all fonts? If it happens with one file, that font file is corrupt and has to be replaced.
